# salesforce javascript remoting and offline support in hybrid mobile app(local or remote) based on salesforce mobile sdk

Tags: javascript-remoting, hybrid-remote, hybrid-local

I have a mobile local hybrid app built upon salesforce mobile sdk. We have offline support in our application and using REST API calls  get the salesforce data.

But now we want to leverage the benefits of JS remoting in our mobile app but also want to do offline support. So I have two choices left with :

1. Create Mobile hybrid remote app which is driven by salesforce visualforce page. So in this I can make JS remote calls. But the problem is here how will we have the offline support? Lets suppose if user opens the app in offline mode will it work?
2. Create local hybrid mobile app and inject the visual force context some how in this like using iframe or via some script. But I find it as a workaround and not the good solution.We have done this ,it works but has some issues.

Please suggest any standard way out for this problem which have both JS remoting + offline support in mobile app.

Thanks,
Manjeet

Comment: SF docs explain how offline mgmt works (incl. with a hybrid app): https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/offline_management.htm . They even provide code samples.